# Icecream sales report Files (Python)

Tags: python, file

*EDIT 11/25/2015*

```
def main():
    outfile=open('icecreams.txt','w')
    sales_report1={'Vanilla':[8580.0,7201.25,8900.0]}
    sales_report2={'Chocolate':[10225.25,9025.0,9505.0]}
    sales_report3={'Rocky Road':[6700.1,5012.45,6011.0]}
    sales_report4={'Cookie Dough':[7901.25,4267.0,7056.5]}
    outfile.write(str(sales_report1)+'\n')
    outfile.write(str(sales_report2)+'\n')
    outfile.write(str(sales_report3)+'\n')
    outfile.write(str(sales_report4)+'\n')
    outfile.close()
    print('Data written to file') 
main()

#read list of icecreams
def main():
    infile=open('icecreams.txt','r')
    sales_report1=str(infile.readline())
    sales_report2=str(infile.readline())
    sales_report3=str(infile.readline())
    sales_report4=str(infile.readline())
    total=sales_report1
    infile.close()
    print(total)
    print(sales_report1,sales_report2,sales_report3,sales_report4)
main()
```

It prints out this:

```
Data written to file
{'Vanilla': [8580.0, 7201.25, 8900.0]}

{'Vanilla': [8580.0, 7201.25, 8900.0]}
 {'Chocolate': [10225.25, 9025.0, 9505.0]}
 {'Rocky Road': [6700.1, 5012.45, 6011.0]}
 {'Cookie Dough': [7901.25, 4267.0, 7056.5]}
```

However I need to add up the sales of each icecream, but when I print the total it prints everything in sales_report1 does this mean that dictionaries is not a good idea in this case?

Comment: Click the [edit] button to add more information to your question.

Comment: I think step 3 and 6 are important, what do they do? And what is the problem? And there is a typo in step 7, an extra `l`.

Comment: How do you get the inputs for icecream sale and why do want a `.txt` file and what is the `7901.25:4267.0:7056.5` in output

Comment: It actually looks like you are trying to make us do your program

Comment: The inputs are given to us as the sales that each store made so I figure I would make one that says store_sales={key(s):element(s),...} as I write that in the file.

Comment: Please try to apply your ideas in Python before approaching the SO community. If you come across any problems then search the forums for a solution and if you are still stick then edit this question.

Comment: What do you mean by  "_Define main as a function_" and "_Define main once more_"?